# How to sequentially subset data so that it sums to a maximum total or less?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I'm at a loss for coding this in R. Any help would be appreciated. I'm trying to subset several data frames, each with hundreds of rows of data. The subset rule:  sequentially analyze the data (from top to bottom) so that the result reflects all the rows that sum to a pre-selected maximum value or less (coming closest to max value if not matching). The output should preserve the sequence of the rows and associated column up to the that point.

As a trivial example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
set.seed(78) # for reproducibility
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 1.1)), ncol = 1, nrow = 5)
dat$type <-c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO")

dat
   V1 type
1 0.1  ABC
2 0.2  DEF
3 0.5  GHI
4 0.8  JKL
5 1.1  MNO
```

Let's say the goal is to sequentially subset `dat` so that the sum of the V1 column is equal to or less than 1.6. In that case, the output would be as follows:

```
    V1 type
1 0.1  ABC
2 0.2  DEF
3 0.5  GHI
4 0.8  JKL
```

Finding this result manually in this example is trivial, of course:

```
dat[1:4,]

   V1 type
1 0.1  ABC
2 0.2  DEF
3 0.5  GHI
4 0.8  JKL
```

Which, of course, sums to 1.6:

```
sum(dat[1:4,1])
[1] 1.6
```

How can I programatically code this in R to run this analysis over many data frames, each with dozens or hundreds of rows and each with a different maximum value target? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a subset condition using `cumsum`, e.g. :

```
s <- dat[cumsum(dat$V1) <= 1.6,]

> s
   V1 type
1 0.1  ABC
2 0.2  DEF
3 0.5  GHI
4 0.8  JKL
```

Comment: This is perfect. Not only does it work, it's simple and efficient. Well done! Meantime, 5 lashes for me for not seeing this to begin with -- so obvious now.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following code:

```
dataframes <- c("dat1", "dat2")
lim <- c(1.6, 1)
dat1 <- data.frame( dat = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 1.1), type = c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO"))
dat2 <- data.frame( dat = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 1.1), type = c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO"))
for (i in 1:length(dataframes))
{data <- get(dataframes[i])
maxitem <- max(which(cumsum(dat$dat)<= lim[i])) 
print(data[1:maxitem,])
}
```